# onValueSelected() is not calling in BarChart, instead onNothingSelected() is calling every time when I click on any bar or anywhere in the BarChart

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I set `OnChartValueSelectedListener` for BarChart but when I click on any bar or anywhere in the BarChart only `onNothingSelected()` is calling and `onValueSelected` is not calling, not even once. I want to get a call back that will tell me which bar has been selected.

I tried setting setOnChartGestureListener() but that also doesn't work.
Please help me to fix the issue.

```
mBarChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
mBarChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(true);
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValsProp1 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < mFeeAmount.size(); i++) {
    float f1 = mFeeAmount.get(i).floatValue();
    float f2 = mFineAmount.get(i).floatValue();

    yValsProp1.add(new BarEntry(i, new float[]{f1, f2}));
}
//Setting data to the bar
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(yValsProp1, " ");
barDataSet.setColors(getColors());
barDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(false);
barDataSet.setDrawValues(true);
BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
barData.setBarWidth(0.55f);
mBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
mBarChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mBarChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

//hiding Axis lines
mBarChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
mBarChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
mBarChart.setFitBars(false);
mBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
mBarChart.setData(barData);
mBarChart.setClipValuesToContent(false);

mBarChart.setVisibleXRange(6, 6);
mBarChart.getLegend().setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
mBarChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got where I was doing wrong, I just removed this line

`barDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(false);`

by default it will be true.